# Empty ViewPager crashes with PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, android-widget

When using a `ViewPager` with `PagerTabStrip`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

with pager having an empty adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()) {

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "test";
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    };
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

App crashes on touching/scrolling the Tab Strip:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.performDrag(ViewPager.java:1990)
```

I *think* [this line in `ViewPager.performDrag()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#1824) might be the cause.

Is it a bug or something wrong with my view setup ?

Comment: just a guess - try to return 1 in getCount() and a valid fragment in getItem(). BTW, width of PagerTabStrip should be fill_parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [`ViewPager` code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) array items are accessed without any checks (when there is no page ):

```
final ItemInfo firstItem = mItems.get(0);
final ItemInfo lastItem = mItems.get(mItems.size() - 1);
```

This causes it to crash.

Comment: were u able to fix this?

Comment: @DeRagan The bug is in support library, so Google devs need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is still not fixed, since i encountered the same problem.
The problem are this two lines in the android ViewPager Class, in the performDrag(float x) method:

```
final ItemInfo firstItem = mItems.get(0);
final ItemInfo lastItem = mItems.get(mItems.size() - 1);
```

There are no checks at all, if the mItems Arraylist is empty or not.
This shouldn't be to hard to fix for the Android Team...

However i came up with a quick and dirty solution i wouldn't suggest to use.
Just make your own class extending ViewPager and override the method, which produces the crash and surround it with a try,catch block:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean event = false;
        try {
            event = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "ERROR: ViewPagerAdapter was empty");
        }
        return event;
    }
}
```

It's **bad practice** to use try, catch blocks for program logic, but until the android team fixes this bug, this is the only solution, which worked for me.

EDIT:

Don't forget to reference your custom ViewPager in the XML:

```
<com.package.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.package.CustomViewPager>
```

Comment: It would be apt to only catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: or just check the size before calling the super and not use exceptions at all